# GRASS GIS r.in.gdal, import multiple band ncdf

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script

I am trying to import a ncdf file with 20000 bands (time steps of precipitation) to grass gis using r.in.gdal. My problem is that i dont need all the bands, only a portion of it, e.g : band 1 to band 200, then band 200 to band 400, etc. The only way i can do that is manually put the numbers of the band in module config '[band=integer[,integer,...]] ', e.g band = 1,2,3,4,5... 200.

Is there a way that a i can put for example like in python 'range(1,200)' and get the 200 first bands of the file?.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for running your GRASS workflow from a python script. If you want to stay with the terminal, then the Linux bash command:  BANDS=`seq --separator="," 1 200` will set the varialbe $BANDS to the list of intergers that you need.

Comment: Hello micha, i put the line in the terminal  band=seq --separator="," 1 200 , but dont work. I tried a python script, like "range(1,200)", but dont work either, im very new in python grass gis with python, i am used to work with terminal. Thanks you

Comment: Typo: `BANDS=$(seq ...)`. Or use backticks instead of `$(` and `)`, but the `$(` and `)` syntax is preferred to bacticks. GIS.SE website doesn't render backticks correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you get started. From a running grass session, start python (or use the built in python console) and enter this script:

```
import grass.script as gscript

ncdf_file = "/path/to/your/netcdf/file.nc"
last = 200
band_list = [str(b) for b in range(1, last)]   
gscript.run_command('r.in.gdal', input=ncdf_file, band=band_list, output="ncdf")
gscript.run_command('g.list', type="rast", pattern="ncdf*")
```